Is the following LMI solvable?
Recently, I have been working on a control problem. The following popular LMI is very interesting:
$PA+A^TP<0$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is known and $P$ is required positive definite.
It is well known that if $A$ is Hurwitz, the above LMI is solvable. However, I'm curious that if $P$ is limited to be a diagonal matrix, viz. $P=\operatorname{diag}(p_1,...,p_n)$, is the LMI still solvable?

In general no, but there are some $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ for which it does exist, such as diagonal Hurwitz $A$ matrices. However, many $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ don't allow for a diagonal $P$ to solve the LMI $P\,A+A^\top P<0$. One such counter example is the following family of $n=2$ cases
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ -a & -b\end{bmatrix},
$$
with $a,b>0$ such that $A$ is Hurwitz. Now using a diagonal $P$ yields
\begin{align}
P\,A+A^\top P &= \begin{bmatrix}p_{11} & 0 \\ 0 & p_{22}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -a & -b\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}0 & -a \\ 1 & -b\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}p_{11} & 0 \\ 0 & p_{22}\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}0 & p_{11}-a\,p_{22} \\ p_{11}-a\,p_{22} & -2\,b\,p_{22}\end{bmatrix}}_Q.
\end{align}
Since the first leading principle minor of $Q$ is always zero it can not be that $Q$ is negative definite and thus the LMI can't be satisfied.

Thanks for your answer. It seems that if $A$ is Hurwitz and $-A$ is diagonally dominant, then a positive definite and diagonal matrix $Q$ exists. It is right?

@Jackie a diagonal $Q$ always exists, since there is always a positive definite solution for $P$ for any given negative definite $Q$ to the equation $P,A+A^\top P=-Q$ if $A$ is Hurwitz. However, reverse does not hold, so given any positive definite $P$ does not imply that the resulting $Q$ is negative definite.
